# MySQL Performance INSERT or (partial) UPDATE if exists, what is best?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, insert

I'm trying to figure out what is "performance wise" the best choice if you have hundred thousands of rows in a MySQL Database that partially get updated frequently.

**INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

This is my current approach where I just insert/update the whole row without checking what actually changed.

**SELECT FROM ... WHERE ID=?** and let PHP Check if something was found

Would this be a better/faster solution? So I trigger an INSERT statement and if the ID exists, I UPDATE the whole row.

Or maybe should I check a step further (in case ID exists) and compare the found row against the updated row in PHP, and then ONLY update the values that have actually changed?

**LOAD DATA Statement**

I have never used this so far and would need to get familiar with, but maybe using this with a REPLACE parameter would be another approach that might speed up the whole import.

Answer (score 0):

Technically an insert will always change an indexed row causing the index to be remade by the engine. But if your update changes the index it's a mute point as the index will still be remade.

This explained in length here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15412865/11005071

Comment: Indexes are BTrees.  They are modified, not rebuilt, when a row is inserted or updated.  Think of each Index as being a Table; When inserting or updating a row of the table's BTree, similar inserts/updates are needed to some or all of the indexes' BTrees.

Comment: Yes, I use a Primary Index and on UPDATE I do NOT overwrite the INDEX Colmun, only the other Clolumns are updated, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your first approach is much better in terms of efficiency and performance. Using simple, shorter lines of code is more efficient than writing query over several lines.
Provided you achieve your intended purpose. And whether you use the second method or first approach should not be your key motivator.
Your real objective should be readability, maintainability, and efficiency.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, everything works as intended with my current solution. Just wasn't sure if it is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t ...;
LOAD DATA ... INTO t ...;
INSERT INTO real_table
    SELECT ... FROM t
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... ;
```

Each step of that is fast and efficient.  The upsert will update existing rows (based on unique keys) or add new rows, as appropriate.

Note that you have a chance to manipulate the data before it gets to the real_table.  The lets you cleanse the data (if needed).  (Load Data with Replace does not provide much chance to cleanse.)

- "hundred thousands of rows" -- No problem.
- "partially updated" -- It does that.
- "Check if something was found" -- Included.

I repeat:  You must have a `UNIQUE` key to let the process know which rows need Updating instead of Inserting.

A crude performance Rule of Thumb:  doing something in a batch (as with my suggestion) is 10 times as fast as doing something one row at a time (as with your Select + check if found).

Comment: Thank you, this is a very interesting approach. I will give it a go and try this on my local system.